# SQL insert adding more than one row unintentionally

Tags: sql, sas, sql-insert

still fairly new to SQL/SAS. I am trying to add a second row to a final table that currently only has one row currently. it is 10 columns long, and below is the code i have now.

```
insert into lib.summary 
    select 
        count(distinct cat_rotn_data.rotn_prng_nbr), 
        1,
        1,
        1,
        avg.avg_blk,
        1,
        avg.avg_duty,
        1,
        1,
        1
    from  avg, cat_rotn_data;
```

It returns the correct numbers in the correct place, but it has 1,089 rows (length of cat_rotn_data) instead of a length of 2 like I wanted. The row that I wish to be row 2 is repeated over a thousand times and im not quite sure why.

Also the values that are 1's right now will be other count / sum calculations from other tables but I took them out to simplify me trying to figure this out.

Comment: If you execute the SELECT stand-alone, does it return what you expect?

Comment: I would suspect it's your cross join, but without seeing some sample data and desired output from your two tables and SELECT statement, it's impossible for us to guide here.

Comment: `from  avg, cat_rotn_data` is a cross join, i.e. Cartesian product. Will return the no of rows in table 1 multiplied by the no of rows in table 2.

Answer (score 1):

You might want a subselect for the counting.  Hard to say exactly without more info

Presume table `avg` has one row.

```
insert into lib.summary 
    select 
        (select 
           count(distinct cat_rotn_data.rotn_prng_nbr)
         from cat_rotn_data
        ),
        1,
        1,
        1,
        avg.avg_blk,
        1,
        avg.avg_duty,
        1,
        1,
        1
    from  avg
```